# Using SvelteKit with smartsheet API npm package to fetch data from smartsheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sveltekit, smartsheet-api

I am trying to learn two things at once (I know, not the greatest of ideas) with SvelteKit and the Smartsheet API.

So far, I have a barebones install of SvelteKit and I'm trying to pull data in from the Smartsheet API to start creating some custom dashboards.

After reading through the Smartsheet API docs a bit, they have a node SDK which I installed via npm and I can see it in the `package.json` as a module. But the question I'm wondering about is how do I get it into SvelteKit. According to the Smartsheet API docs, for node this is an example to call it in:

```
var client = require('smartsheet');
var smartsheet = client.createClient({ accessToken: ll35xxxxxxxxxxxxae05 });
```

So, I've added this into the `app.html` file in my SvelteKit project just to test. I replaced the `accessToken` with the one on my Smartsheet account and then just to test, I did a `condsole.log(smartsheet)` but then when I inspect the source I see `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in the console.

I'm not sure if I am going about the correctly overall. I feel that I need to add an `import` so that it can pull in the smartsheet API module in, but I'm not sure where I would add that for SvelteKit? Should it be in the `svelte.config.js` or somewhere else? Again, I am new to this so I'm trying to figure this out as I go along.

Comment: AFAIK SvelteKit is using [ES6 Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) with `import` statement.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa - So would that be something like this: `import client from 'smartsheet';`. I tried that and then I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`. I'm starting to wonder if this SvelteKit is not the best route at this time. Might look into the python side of things.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` usually means the package is only useable in server-side Node.js environment, because `process` (UNIX process functions) is not available in client-side JavaScript code

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa - Hmmm, ok. I was under the assumption that SvelteKit has a prepackaged server (at least that's what it appears to me when running `npm run dev -- --open`). So, again, not really sure if I need to install another package to get it to work, or if there is something else that I am missing?

Comment: Yes, it has a server for development work, but SvelteKit is a frontend development framework, so you are misunderstanding.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa - Ok, so for the sake of moving on (and if anyone ever has this issue) what would be a reasonable solution? Open to ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Check how smartsheet works in plain JS/HTML and then go from there. Anything that works in vanilla browser JS will work in SvelteKit.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I've added this into the app.html file in my SvelteKit project just to test.

This is a nice debug step. It helps to demonstrate that this has nothing to do with svelte and everything to do with the fact that the smartsheet API package was built for the node runtime, not the browser. Besides the package itself, you should also consider CORs and whether you'd be leaking secrets to the browser.

In general, though, you really shouldn't need to touch the `app.html` file at all. That's where the framework comes into play.

---

**My suggestions:**

**[!] Exposing secrets to the browser.** The fact that you need to blot out your `accessToken` in the code snippet suggests that you almost certainly do not want to be making API calls from the browser.

You can add server-side REST API calls using [**endpoints**](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints). So, for example, you might make a GET request to an in-app endpoint during [page loading](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading).

If you use endpoints, you'll need to use an adapter that supports them (e.g. `adapter-node`).

---

The [realworld example app](https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld) demonstrates these patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the input! My intent was _just_ to test to see if I could make a connection. All of this is being done locally in a docker container on a hypervisor machine (proxmox) that I built. This is **NOT** production ready code by any means. That being said, I will take a look at the realworld svelte repo you listed. I would also like to note that I did _sorta_ get this to work by ditching SvelteKit and using node directly. I was also looking at the older API docs from Smatrsheet as well. This is the update JS SDK they have: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-javascript-sdk